# AVCaptureSession didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, uiimage, format, avcapturesession, didreceivememorywarning

While capturing the images as a session of AVCaptureSession is running into a local NSMutableArray I receive a didReceiveMemoryWarning call. after testing it a little bit, I found it happens when the ARRAY reaches a certain count.

I assume it's because I'm using UIImage as the type of object I add to the array. 
What would be the best format to save those images in?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

CVPixelBufferRef pixel_buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixel_buffer];
CGImageRef ref = [self.context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent]; 

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

CGImageRelease(ref);

[self.capturingImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];
if (saveImages == YES) { //this a BOOL value that becomes YES when the user clicks the RECORDING button.
    [dImagesArray addObject:image];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the images in whatever format is most appropriate for your needs: this will probably be either JPG or PNG. The former is smaller, but lossy, the latter is lossless. So if image quality is extremely important to you, use PNG. If not, I'd use JPGs (which will have the added advantage of using up less space on disk).

You're currently not saving any of your images to disk, just keeping them around in memory in an array, and that's what's causing you problems. You could handle this in a number of ways, depending on what you want your app to do. Do you *need* to save your images to disk? If so, maybe set a limit on the number of images allowed in memory at any one time and dump them to disk when required. Or perhaps you're just doing some analysis on the images, in which case you can just release them when you no longer require them.

Comment: Thanks lxt. So, do you mean I should change the type in which I keep the images in the array to NSData using "NSData *UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);"?

Answer (score 1):

why not use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer unless you are doing any kind of filtering? For performance reasons i would recommend using OpenGL to render image for  delegate method `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` Here is an example... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html